# How do I install a template (CSS & JS) with Webpackers in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to install [this theme - Cleopatra - built on Tailwind CSS](https://github.com/moesaid/cleopatra) in my Rails 6 app, but I can't quite make heads & tails of how to do it properly with webpacker.

I am sure this should be fairly straightforward, but I don't use any JS frameworks so I don't quite get webpacker and JS package managers other than knowing they are similar to Bundler and Gemfiles.

I have Tailwind CSS successfully installed, and I have tried a variety of things and all generate errors or don't render successfully.

So I would rather just a step by step approach to installing it.

I am using `Rails 6.0.3.6` and `Ruby 3.0.1p64`.

**Edit 1**

I have been trying [the following guide](https://rubyyagi.com/how-to-integrate-html-bootstrap-theme-into-rails-6/) and this is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-3!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss)
┃ Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
┃ ReferenceError: window is not defined
┃     at Object.<anonymous> (/ACA/node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:6:345884)
┃     at Module._compile (/ACA/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
┃     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
┃     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
┃     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
┃     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
┃     at require (/ACA/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
┃     at Object.<anonymous> (/ACA/postcss.config.js:5:5)
┃     at Module._compile (/ACA/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
┃     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
┃     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
┃     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
┃     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
┃     at require (/ACA/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
┃     at module.exports (/ACA/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js:28:9)
┃     at loadJs (/ACA/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js:9:18)
┃     at Explorer.loadFileContent (/ACA/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/createExplorer.js:230:12)
┃     at /ACA/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/createExplorer.js:252:21
┃  @ ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss 2:26-228
┃  @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
┃
```

This is my `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
const images = require.context('../img', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

import "../packs/cleopatra";
import "../stylesheets/application.scss";

// import "apexcharts";
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
window.ApexCharts = ApexCharts; // return apex chart
```

This is my `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('apexcharts'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

This is my `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss`:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "cleopatra";
```

I have added `apexcharts` via `yarn`.

Both of my custom files are `app/javascript/stylesheets/cleopatra.css` and `app/javascript/packs/cleopatra.js`.

This is in my `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

**Edit 2**

I am using `webpacker 4.3.0`, and you can see what `packs/cleopatra.js` [looks like here](https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/5090299e19228930d44375ae6bcf9598).

Comment: Although it is for Bootstrap, this article helped me a lot to integrate a Tailwind theme with Webpacker. The principles are the same. Check it: https://rubyyagi.com/how-to-integrate-html-bootstrap-theme-into-rails-6/

Comment: That's an intriguing idea. Thanks for the link. I will check it out.

Comment: @PedroSchmitt I tried that and it took me part of the way there, but I am encountering a myriad of weird JS errors that are frustrating me :| So I am hoping someone can just give me a comprehensive rundown of how to do it.

Comment: try moving `tailwindcss`, `autoprefix` and `apexcharts` below `postcss-import` in `postcss.config.js`.

Comment: @Chandan that didn't work unfortunately :( Any more ideas?

Comment: what webpack version you used and can you add what's in `packs/cleopatra`

Comment: try this [blog](https://davidteren.medium.com/rails-6-and-tailwindcss-getting-started-42ba59e45393)

Comment: @Chandan I updated the question with both the webpacker version and the contents of `packs/cleopatra.js`. Also, that blog post is just about setting up Tailwind CSS in Rails. It's not about applying a Tailwind CSS template (two different things altogether).

Comment: @marcamillion remove `apexcharts` from `postcss.config.js` this package does not contain any css that need to be process

Comment: @Chandan I tried that and it doesn't fix this issue :(

Comment: @marcamillion are you still getting the same issue, I created project with same configuration now it is working on my setup, can you share if there any change in errors

Comment: Can you share your project in a Github repo so I can see? I am getting the same `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Also, if possible, can you also push it to Heroku so I can see the theme in action?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232924/discussion-between-chandan-and-marcamillion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. cloned cleopatra theme repo locally

```
git clone https://github.com/moesaid/cleopatra.git moesaid_cleopatra
```

2. `rails new s_67585007 --no-ri --no-rdoc`
3. `rails g controller home index`
4. added root route in `config/routes.rb`

```
root 'home#index'
```

5. added tailwindcss package with requirements

```
yarn add tailwindcss@compat postcss@7 autoprefixer@9
```

6. `postcss.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    // require('apexcharts'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

7.`cp moesaid_cleopatra/dist/js/script.js s_67585007/app/javascript/packs/cleopatra.js`

8. copied style, images and javascript file inside public folder

```
cp moesaid_cleopatra/dist/{css,img} s_67585007/public
```

9. `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test67585007</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/css/pro.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">  
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'cleopatra', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

10. copied html from `moesaid_cleopatra/dist/index.html` pasted in `app/views/layouts/home/index.html.erb` and adjusted with `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` changes can be checked [here](https://github.com/ChandanChainani/cleopatra_rails/blob/main/app/views/home/index.html.erb)
11. `app/javascript/packs/application.js`

```
import "../stylesheets/application.scss";

import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
window.ApexCharts = ApexCharts; // return apex chart
```

12. `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

then start `rails server`

Note: You may need to install some extra package has during compilation shows package missing `clipboard`